# add stop onmouse over to this simple code

Tags: javascript, text, timer, onmouseover

I would like to add a 'onmouseover stop' setting to this piece of code. This is because I plan to write long bits of text and I would like to give the reader a change to stop the text from changing in case they haven't stopped reading.

I have found similar questions but they relate to stopping a marquee from scrolling on mouseover. Ive tried adding the same code that seems to make a marquee stop but it just makes my code stop working all together.

```
<div id="changeText" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var text = ["1", "2", "3"];
    var counter = 0;
    var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
    setInterval(change, 5000);
    function change() {
       elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
       counter++;
       if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and `onmouseover` code have you tried?

Comment: Yeah. Please link to the question you have already found.

Comment: Ive found that i need to add this "document.getElementById("changeText").onmouseover = stop; and then again document.getElementById("slideshow").onmouseout = start;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `clearInterval()` and pass the intervalId returned by your `setInterval()` call on a mouseover event, then restart on mouseout, as shown in the updated sample code below:

```
<div onmouseover="stop()" onmouseout="start()" id="changeText" ></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text = ["1", "2", "3"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
var intervalId;
start();

function start() {
    intervalId = setInterval(change, 5000);
    function change() {
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
    }
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}

</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much zerga! i guess i was barking up the wrong tree :\